# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed after saving the file

Tags: excel, vba

The code I'm trying to write should simply check the different price book entries in my companies system. It should take a purchase order from the past and check which would have been the cheapest price book entry for a specific minimum order quantety.
Before doing that the code defines a Range `PBRange` which then should be sorted to work with 'if' clauses afterwards.
When defining the `PBRange` the error 1004 occurs.

When I save and reopen the file a message pops up that there was a problem found with some content in the file. After asking me to recover it the code doesn't work anymore.
The strange thing is that the code worked perfectly fine in the beginning.

```
Public PBRange As Range
Public PO As Worksheet
Public PB As Worksheet

Sub CheapestPrice()


Dim LastRowPO As Long
Dim LastRowPB As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set PO = Worksheets("Purchase Orders")
Set PB = Worksheets("Price Book")

'!!!Here the error occurs!!!
Set PBRange = PB.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

The code after is just an if else combination with two for loops to work through the 2 worksheets. This should work perfeclty fine.

I expect a range to sort afterwards with different criteria.

Comment: An immediate problem I see is improper referencing. The Worksheets are not linked to a workbook, and in the `Set PBRange` line you have a Range object not linked to any sheet or wb. The latter is giving me the same error as you're having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing correctly is *key* to prevent errors. Even if they don't show up immediately, those errors will pop up and tackle your code sooner than later.

Correct referencing could be, for example:

```
Option Explicit

Public PBRange As Range
Public PO As Worksheet
Public PB As Worksheet

Sub CheapestPrice()
Dim LastRowPO As Long, LastRowPB As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set PO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchase Orders")
Set PB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price Book")

Set PBRange = PB.Range("A1", PB.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

End Sub
```

In case you do not specify both the workbook and worksheet, like with `Range("A1")`, VBA will assume the *active* workbook and worksheet. If these are **not** what you intend to refer to, you will likely get an error. You could make your life easier by using a `With...End With` statement to prevent a lot of typing. E.g.:

```
Sub example()
Dim LRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox LRow

    .Range("D1:D" & LRow).Value = "NewValue"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this was fast! I'm a VBA beginner so thank you very much for this tip!! I'll google a bit more about correct referencing to prevent errors like that in the future!

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking the check icon below the downvote button :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Public PBRange As Range
Public PO As Worksheet, PB As Worksheet

Sub test()
    Dim LastRowA As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set PO = .Worksheets("Purchase Orders")
        Set PB = .Worksheets("Price Book")
    End With

    With PB
        'Find Sheet PB & Column A last row
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'With out using LastRowA variable
        Set PBRange = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        'Using LastRowA variable
        Set PBRange = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowA)
    End With

End Sub
```